# Removing message after wfs-t transaction

Tags: openlayers-2, wfs-t

Is there a way to remove the `alert` message after adding new objects to
the database with WFS-T. I am using code from demo example from GeoServer. The
code is shown below

```
  var drawPoint = new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(
                roads, OpenLayers.Handler.Point,
                {displayClass: 'olControlDrawFeaturePoint'}
            );
            drawPoint.featureAdded = function(feature) {
                feature.layer.eraseFeatures([feature]);
                // cast to multipoint
                feature.geometry = new OpenLayers.Geometry.MultiPoint(
                    feature.geometry
                );
                feature.style.strokeColor = "#0000ff";
                feature.state = OpenLayers.State.INSERT;

                feature.layer.drawFeature(feature);
            }
```

Is there a way to remove this alert. Or maybe just to get the part SUCCESS
or FAILED??